# Can't list Direct Conference template on Polycom RPRM API

Tags: api, video-conferencing

I'm building a Python Polycom Rest API wrapper library.

I can't find a way to list the Direct Conference template on the RPRM.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i found a way by parsing reservations list links.

The URL endpoint to use is :

/api/rest/conference-templates/